# Считается ли высталенная по координатам метка за запрос к Яндекс.Карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

У меня два вопроса:

1. Считается ли операция, выставления метки по заранее известным координатам, за запрос к сервисам Яндекс.Карт?
2. В разеделе "Условия использования бесплатной версии MapKit" есть пункт:

   > Приложение, использующее MapKit, не должно отслеживать транспорт, людей или другие объекты в реальном времени.

   Означает ли это, что я не могу в бесплатной версии MapKit выставлять метку по координатам пользователя, если эти координаты получены не посредством использования MapKit?

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, вашу реальную задачу. Под отслеживанием в общем случае понимается мониторинг в реальном времени и  turn-by-turn навигация, но без конкретики вам никто не ответит.

Comment: Выставлять метку по неважно откуда полученным координатам можно, это не является платным запросом (если не вызвать геокодирование для определения адреса, конечно). Но проще получать её средствами MapKit, определять геопозицию совершенно точно не запрещено.

Comment: @Reni, Из базы данных берутся координаты точек, и по средствам Yandex MapKit по этим координатам выставляются метки на карту. Так же есть кнопка определения местоположения пользователя, которая по факту тоже выставляет метку по координатам пользователя, которые получены НЕ через MapKit. Учитывая все это - вопрос: не нарушаю ли я условий использования бесплатной версии MapKit и не превышу ли 25 000 запросов к сервисам Яндекс.Карт в сутки?

Comment: В такой формулировке не нарушаете

Comment: @Reni, Спасибо.